# Доступ к SharedPreferences в Service

Tags: java, android

Возник вопрос связанный с получением данных из памяти телефона в Сервисе.
Делаю примерно так

```
public class Fon extends Service {
   SharedPreferences sPref;
   String SAVED_LOGIN = "login";
   sPref = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
   savedLogin = sPref.getString(SAVED_LOGIN, "");
}
```

Естественно это не сработало, оно подчеркивает
`sPref = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);`
Как  правильно воплотить данную цель в жизнь?

Comment: `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Объявите переменную в `SharedPreferences sPref`. А вот инициализацию проводите уже внутри тела метода, например в `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```